# Laravel Test api Post MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5

Hello I'm using **Laravel 5.5** and have in my test

```
public function testCreate()
    {
        $userAdmin = factory(User::class)->create();
        $roleAdmin = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();

        $userAdmin->roles()->attach($roleAdmin);

        $this->actingAs($userAdmin)->post('/api/object/create')
            ->assertJson(["success"=>true]);
    }
```

In my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
   Route::group(['prefix'=>'object'], function(){
      Route::post('create', 'ObjectController@create')->middleware('can:create,App\Models\Object');
   });
});
```

But when I run my test return:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException

I have already tried to clear my route with:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

And with:

```
$this->actingAs($userAdmin, 'api')->post('/api/object/create')
```

And

```
$this->actingAs($userAdmin, 'api')->post('/object/create')
```

My Policy function that I use in my middleware API is:

```
public function create(User $user){
   return $user->isAdmin();
}
```

But it doesn't work. What I'm wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `php artisan route:list`? Is this route in `web.php` or `api.php`?

Comment: it is in api.php
the output is:
POST | api/object/create|| App\Http\Controllers\ObjectController@create | api,auth:api,can:create,App\Models\Object

Comment: You say you tried to clear routes with `php artisan route:cache`, but to clear routes you would use `route:clear`. Did you use the wrong command, or is that just a mistake in the question?

Comment: Can you include the full output of `route:list` in the question? I'm trying to rule out another route unintentionally matching the request instead of the intended route definition.

Answer (score 0):

you need to login because you have auth middleware.